# Getting filename from PhotoPrevs.append

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the snippet to Preview uploaded image using jQuery on a user registration from.

```
for(var i=0,l=imgs.length; i<l; i++){
                            $PhotoPrevs.append('<img src="uploads/'+ imgs[i].filename +'?d='+ (new Date()).getTime() +'" />');

                        }
```

I'm trying to **write** photo url dynamically on form input field where "**link**" is the name of target input field by `document.myform.link.value` function.

How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Jquery you can do this in the following manner.

```
$(function() {
  var url = "some url here"
  $('.myform input[name="link"]').val(url);
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aqj48y2y/6/)**